# I am trying to get two columns first of name and second of increment by 60. But i am getting 0 in every row of second column

Tags: javascript

//X is not increased instead getting 0 in each column.

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < users.length; x += 60) {
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(i);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = users[i];
        cell2.innerHTML = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(var x=0;x<users.length;x+=60){` runs only one time. because your `x` increase by 60 each time and maybe your users is less than 60. http://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/kj90jje3/

Comment: I change the code to `for(var x=0;x<users.length;x++){` its getting better I think. http://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/kj90jje3/1/

Comment: You should paste exactly the type of output you are expecting to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you do not need nested loops:

```
var users = ["User_01", "User_02", "User_03"];
var x = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell();
    var cell2 = row.insertCell();
    cell1.innerHTML = users[i];
    cell2.innerHTML = x;
    x += 60;
}
```